# Returning Count of records from sys_refcursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle Version : 11.2.0.2

I have a table ABC which has n number of columns , out of which I need COUNT of status, age and type columns individually  to be given as OUT parameters to other application.

My Other application ( web application ) would display these as below:

STATUS              10

AGE                    05

TYPE                   20

where in 10 , 05 , 20 are COUNT of values from table ABC which I need to pass on to the web application.

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Where does the `sys_refcursor` from the title come in to play?  It sounds like you want a stored procedure that has three scalar `out` parameters that can be populated by a single query within the procedure.  I don't see anything that would use a `sys_refcursor`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to us a SELECT statement along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) AS STATUS_COUNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT AGE)    AS AGE_COUNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE)   AS TYPE_COUNT
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Alternatively, if you just want a count of the values, use

```
SELECT COUNT(STATUS) AS STATUS_COUNT,
       COUNT(AGE)    AS AGE_COUNT,
       COUNT(TYPE)   AS TYPE_COUNT
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Best of luck.

Comment: It's not clear that the poster wants `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` he may just want a `COUNT()` (i.e., of non-null values)

Comment: HI All, Thanks for your replies.

I need to write a procedure or a function which returns the count of status , age and type which should satisfy the below criteria

select * from ABC
where ABC_id = 2001
and ABC_LEVEL_ID = 1 --status
and ABC_REQUEST_DATE < sysdate --age
and ABC_TYPE_ID = 5; --type
 
If ABC_ID = 2001 and ABC_LEVEL_ID = 1 
THEN return COUNT(STATUS)

Similarly for age ans type also.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there can be two approaches which can be insorporated to satisfy your goal.

1) Using ref cursor to OUT the count's

2) Using scalar variables to OUT the params.

Since i dont have workspace with me please pardon any syntax error.

```
--1) Using refcursor
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_out_ref(
        p_ref_out OUT sys_refcursor )
    AS
    BEGIN
      OPEN p_ref_out FOR 
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) STATUS_COUNT,
      COUNT(DISTINCT AGE) AGE_COUNT,
      COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) TYPE_COUNT
      FROM YOUR_TABLE ;
    END;

    --2 nd approach may be just passing the count value to scalar variables as OUT param

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_out_ref(
        p_status_cnt_out  OUT NUMBER,
        p_age_cnt_out     OUT NUMBER,
        p_type_cnt_out    OUT NUMBER)
    AS
    BEGIN

      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) STATUS_COUNT,
      COUNT(DISTINCT AGE) AGE_COUNT,
      COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) TYPE_COUNT
      INTO
      p_status_cnt_out,
      p_age_cnt_out,
      p_type_cnt_out
      FROM YOUR_TABLE ;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If suddenly someone are looking for how to get only a number of rows in sys_refcursor
without knowing the structure of the data of that cursor, then there is simplest and neat solution ever:

```
declare
l_cursor   sys_refcursor;
l_cur_id   number;
l_rowcount number := 0;
begin
  l_cursor := some_function_returning_cursor();
  -- solution starts
  l_cur_id := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(l_cursor);
  WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cur_id) > 0 LOOP
    l_rowcount := l_rowcount + 1;
  end loop;
  -- solution ends
  dbms_output.put_line('number of rows is ' || l_rowcount);
end;
```

Note that after this you will not able to read from cursor because it fetched/closed already.

Documentation:

- `DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68279
- `DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68267